# Access global list from variable list in Jinja2

Tags: loops, jinja2, nested-loops

I have an inventory file looks like this.

```
--- 
active: 
  hosts: 
    host2: "1.1.1.2"
    .
    .
    .
passive: 
  hosts: 
    host1: "1.1.1.1"
    .
    .
    .

datacenter: 
  active:
  passive:
```

Data varies time to time but the elements to get to list always there "datacenter"
I want to access datacenter variable and whatever in the list I would like to look into whole data and iterate over via Jinja.

My initial thought below would be suffice but that is not the case.

```
{% for i in datacenter%}
# Listing {{ i }} hosts
     {% for item in i %}
       HOST {{ item }}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This outputs:

```
# Listing active hosts
       HOST a
       HOST c
       HOST t
       HOST i
       HOST v
       HOST e

# Listing passive hosts
       HOST p
       HOST a
       HOST s
       HOST s
       HOST i
       HOST v
       HOST e
```

Expected output:

```
# Listing active hosts
       HOST 1.1.1.2
       HOST n

# Listing passive hosts
       HOST 1.1.1.1
       HOST n
```

Comment: Could you include the relevant source code where you read this inventory file, transform to a Python data object (i.e. into a simple `dict`), and then pass it as a template variable to a Jinja2 render function?

Comment: I was using this service https://j2live.ttl255.com/

Comment: I think it's not possible to access template variables dynamically using this online service. In order to do that, you have to pack all the variables inside a new `dict` and pass it to the template as an additional variable, named e.g. `ALL`, then you can use dynamic dict key lookup like this: `{{ ALL[i].hosts  }}`, where `i` is the loop variable over 'datacenter'.